# Recursion in Groovy with closure

Tags: recursion, groovy, closures

I am currently trying to understand a problem with recursion. This code checks to see if a node is a leaf node, if it is it will increment the amount of leaf nodes.

I can't understand what the fn.call(this) does and then how it then calls the closure inside the for loop.

Here is my code.

```
class TreeNode {
    String name
    List<TreeNode> children = []

    // if no children, there is no leaf node
    boolean isLeaf() {
        return !children
    }

    void walkTree(Closure fn) {
        fn.call(this)
        for (child in children) {
            child.walkTree(fn)
        }
    }

}

testTreeNode = new TreeNode(name: "Fred", children: [
            new TreeNode(name: "Janet", children: [
                    new TreeNode(name: "Mark"),
                    new TreeNode(name: "Anne", children: [new TreeNode(name: "Simon") ]),
                    new TreeNode(name: "Kelly")
            ]),
            new TreeNode(name: "Nigel")
    ])

   def leafCount = 0

  testTreeNode.walkTree { node -> if (node.leaf) leafCount++}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I'm following correctly, but it seems you have 2 questions:

**1. What does `fn.call(this)` do?**

Firstly, a Closure is an anonymous block of code that can be executed at a later time.

When you call `testTreeNode.walkTree`, you are passing the Closure (block of anonymous code) `node -> if (node.leaf) leafCount++` as a parameter of the `walkTree` method, so that closure becomes the variable named `fn` within the context of `walkTree`.

Within the `walkTree` method, the Closure (block of code) is then being explicitly invoked using the Closure.call(args) method.

See: http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_calling_a_closure

**2. How is the closure executed inside the for loop?**

As the closure can be referred to using the `fn` variable name, you are then able to pass that as an argument directly to `walkTree` for each child TreeNode in the loop, which then invokes that closure using `fn.call(this)`.

If we substitute the Closure usage with the block of code passed, it might be clearer what is happening:

```
void walkTree(Closure fn) {
    //Closure executed here
    if (this.leaf) leafCount++

    for (child in children) {
        //closure passed as argument to walkTree method of child TreeNodes
        child.walkTree { node -> if (node.leaf) leafCount++ }
    }
}
```